# Clarification of a proof regarding real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, real-numbers

I'm reading the [following proof](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/350/RUnique.pdf) on real numbers being the only complete ordered field (up to isomorphism).

The author constructs the following bijection $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow k$ and for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ defines

$\varphi(\alpha):=\sup \{\varphi(q): q<\alpha, q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$,

$S(\alpha):=\{\varphi(q): q<\alpha, q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

$\varphi(\alpha):=\sup S(\alpha)$.

Afterwards he starts working on the lemma: if $\alpha<\beta$ then $\varphi(\alpha)<\varphi(\beta)$ and invites us to observe

$\alpha<\beta \quad \Longrightarrow \quad S(\alpha) \subset S(\beta) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sup S(\alpha) \leq \sup S(\beta) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \varphi(\alpha) \leq \varphi(\beta) $

Now my question is why is there a $\leq$ sign between $\sup S(\alpha)$ and $\sup S(\beta)$? Why not immediately $<$? I can't come up with any example where 2 real numbers would not be equal but have the same $\sup$ as defined here so any help clarifying that would be appreciated.

P.S. Later on it's actually proved that $\varphi$ is strictly order preserving, so there no possibility of $\alpha<\beta$ and $\varphi(\alpha) = \varphi(\beta)$, but why is this not immediately obvious?

Comment: That is what you can conclude in the second implication by using only the hypothesis that $S(\alpha)\subset S(\beta)$ and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $A \subset B$ then $\sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$. The strict inequality might be deducible from the context, but for the sake of brevity if it is enough to use the general fact (without reference even) then it's worth doing it, to keep the proof short and easy to follow.